# Can I change the menus on the default browser?

Tags: browser

I have an Evo running Froyo and love it.

But...

In the default browser (which I am happy with)  the menu options are Back, Forward, Add Bookmarks, Bookmarks, Windows and More. Thing is, I share links with the cloud (Twitter, Facebook, Reader, Dropbox, etc.) much more than adding bookmarks. I use Chrome so that all my bookmarks are shared between all my computers, so on, phone bookmarks are where ideas go to die. How can I move Add Bookmarks to More and bring Share forward?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No - as far as I can tell you can't change the menu in an application (unless that application specifically has that feature).  You could try downloading another browser like [Opera](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.opera.browser&feature=search_result), [Firefox 4](https://market.android.com/details?id=org.mozilla.firefox&feature=search_result), or [Dolphin](https://market.android.com/details?id=mobi.mgeek.TunnyBrowser&feature=search_result) (just to name a few).

That being said, if you still want to use the default browser, you can "long-press" on the address bar and a context menu will pop up with the option to "Share page". You can use that instead.

Hope this helps.